# Basic HTTP Auth using Paw

Tags: python, python-requests, paw-app

I've got a small python script that is able to access my API correctly using the following code

```
import requests
auth = requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth(user, password)
furl="http://10.101.0.203:8080/imcrs/plat/res/device"
r = requests.get(f_url, auth=auth )
```

In this case, the auth object works perfectly ( it's able to send the GER requests and the auth object is able to authenticate successfully and I get the expected content with a HTTP 200 response )

looking at the python code generated by PAW

```
def send_request():
    # My API
    # GET http://10.101.0.203:8080/imcrs/plat/res/device

    try:
        response = requests.get(
            url="http://10.101.0.203:8080/imcrs/plat/res/device",
            params={
                "resPrivilegeFilter": "false",
                "start": "0",
                "size": "10",
                "orderBy": "id",
                "desc": "false",
                "total": "false",
            },
            headers={
                "AuthorizationBasic Og==": "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=",
                "Cookie": "JSESSIONID=D1B20BF4BB2FC9F458C8A45821FE0BDB",
            },
        )
        print('Response HTTP Status Code: {status_code}'.format(
            status_code=response.status_code))
        print('Response HTTP Response Body: {content}'.format(
            content=response.content))
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        print('HTTP Request failed')
```

it appears that PAW is encoding the auth string and sending then in the headers which results in an immediate 401 error.

Is the headers the same as the auth object created above? Trying to figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. That's right, it seems like our Python "Requests" code generator isn't handling Basic Auth propertly. I'll look into this and ship a fix, thanks for reporting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your working python code you are using `HTTPDigestAuth` this is not the same as `Basic auth` paw currently does not support HTTPDigestAuth.

Comment: Update on here Paw know has digest auth (not used in the code generator but can be used when sending from Paw) https://paw.cloud/extensions/DigestAuthDynamicValue